# Pytorch cannot open libgomp-a34b3233.so.1

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch, oserror

I have been using PyTorch for year now and out of nowhere, couple days ago I got this error when importing `torch`:

```py
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jechos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    _load_global_deps()
  File "/home/jechos/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 154, in _load_global_deps
    ctypes.CDLL(lib_path, mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/mnt/disk/Linux/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libgomp-a34b3233.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to delete and recreate the environment (btw, this broke torch on my other environments also), I tried to follow this post: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/643

Nothing seems to work.
I don't really now what happened.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Reinstalling torch is not a problem, I can recreate `conda` environment.

Some infos:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- CUDA 11.6 with Driver 510.108.03
- CuDNN 8.6.0
- GPU: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q]
- Python 3.8.16
- Pip 23.1.2
- Conda 4.11.0
- torch 2.0.1

I installed `torch` following [the official documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/):
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio`